# SQL not finding results

Tags: sql, delphi, ms-access

This query currently is returning no results, and it should. Can you see anything wrong with this query

field title are NEED_2_TARGET, ID,  and CARD

NEED_2_TARGET = integer

CARD = string

ID = integer

value of name is 'Ash Imp'

```
{this will check if a second target is needed}
//**************************************************************************
function TFGame.checkIf2ndTargetIsNeeded(name: string):integer;
//**************************************************************************
var
  targetType : integer; //1 is TCard , 2 is TMana , 0 is no second target needed.
begin
    TargetType := 0;
    Result := targetType;
       with adoquery2 do
        begin
          close;
          sql.Clear;
          sql.Add('SELECT * FROM Spells WHERE CARD = '''+name+''' and NEED_2_TARGET = 1');
          open;
        end;

        if adoquery2.RecordCount < 1 then
          Result := 0
       else
         begin
           Adoquery2.First;
           TargetType := adoquery2.FieldByName(FIELD_TARGET_TYPE).AsInteger;
           result := TargetType;
         end;

end;
```

sql db looks like below

```
ID  CARD    TRIGGER_NUMBER  CATEGORY_NUMBER QUANTITY    TARGET_NUMBER   TYPE_NUMBER PLUS_NUMBER PERCENT STAT_TARGET_NUMBER  REPLACEMENT_CARD_NUMBER MAX_RANDOM  LIFE_TO_ADD REPLACED_DAMAGE NEED_2_TARGET   TYPE_OF_TARGET
27  Ash Imp     2                   2          15             14                                                                                                                                  1             1
```

Comment: show your data to prove your assumption.

Comment: Please edit your question to provide data that should match but isn't. Also, if you use parameterized queries, they execute faster (they're only compiled once) and you can eliminate all of the `"'+name+'"` garbage. You should also not be using `SQL.Add` without `SQL.Clear` first, and if you're using a single statement you can just use `SQL.Text` to replace the entire SQL statement with a single line of code. `Add` appends to the end of existing SQL, which means you may not be executing what you think.

Comment: i know it returns no results cause i trace threw it and whent i get to `if adoquery2.RecordCount < 1 then
          Result := 0`  it gives me result 0

Comment: @GordonLinoff all fields in db are all caps

Comment: You're not reading what we're asking. We want **data that should match that isn't**, not another statement that you're not getting results.

Comment: @KenWhite i am using `sql.Clear`  but thats not the issue, it seems to be my sql statement thats why i just posted that.. and what you mean by provide data that should match but isnt

Comment: You say you have data in your DB that should match, but you're not getting any matches. **Post the data that should match**, and show what you're using as the value in `name` in the query.

Comment: @KenWhite added not manually but copy paste from the db and the compiler

Comment: That doesn't look like "fields are NEED_2_TARGET, ID, and CARD", and your reply to Gordon (who said "Access is case sensitive when comparing **values**") was "all fields in db are all caps" - "Ash Imp"  doesn't appear to be ALL CAPS to me. With that being said, I don't see anything wrong with your query based on the information you've provided (presuming it's now accurate).

Comment: @KenWhite i made mistake i meant field titles, but you see the data, you can see what is in all caps, what the name is in  db and what i am searching. unless you have not looked at the data you wanted me to add?

Comment: When that was said, you were *ignoring requests to post the data*, so I could not *see what was in all caps*. (That's why I asked you to **post the data in the first place**.)

Comment: @KenWhite you made that post after i added the data...

Comment: That's incorrect, and the revision history and time stamps on the comments prove otherwise. I'll leave you (and your problem) alone. Good luck.

Comment: @KenWhite  edited 33 mins ago  your post 25 mins ago

Comment: @GlenMorse, do not use recordcount but use EOF.

Comment: Is this Q `[delphi]` specific?

Comment: @GordonLinoff re: "Access is case sensitive when comparing values" - No, it is not. Look [here](http://pastebin.com/Wi5B0Bwh).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is  or was an issue with the

```
With Adoquery2 do
begin
...
end
```

when using `name` in the sql, it was really getting  `adoquery2.name`  not the var name. I fixed this by changing `name` to `Cname` had no more issues after that.

Comment: And **with** strikes again! It's made worse by the fact that you couldn't easily notice the problem using the eval tooltip over `Name` - because that doesn't work! @GlenMorse you've just suffered your first bite from the **with** statement. I strongly recommend that you rather eliminate **with** altogether, otherwise you risk still more bad experiences in the future. The point is that **with** can always be easily changed to a local variable alias, so there's absolutely no need to subject yourself to the risk.

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of things that could be going wrong.

First and most important in your trouble-shooting is to take your query and run it directly against your database. I.e. first confirm your query is correct by eliminating possibilities of other things going wrong. More things confirmed working, the less "noise" to distract you from solving the problem.

1. As others having pointed out if you're not clearing your SQL statement, you could be returning zero rows in your *first* result set.

   - *Yes I know, you've since commented that you **are** clearing your previous query*. The point is: if you're having trouble solving your problem, how can you be ***sure*** where the problem lies? So, **don't leave out potentially relevant information**!
2. Which bring us neatly to the second possibility. I can't see the rest of your code, so I have to ask: are you refreshing your data after changing your query? If you don't `Close` and `Open` your query, you may be looking at a previous execution's result set.

   - I'm unsure whether you're even allowed to change your query text while the component is `Active`, or even whether that depends on exactly which data access component you're using. The point is, it's worth checking.
3. Is your application connecting to the correct database? Since you're using Access, it's very easy to be connected to a different database file without realising it.

   - You can check this by changing your query to return all rows (i.e. delete the WHERE clause).
4. You my want to change the quotes used in your SQL query. Instead of: `...CARD = "'+name+'" ORDER...` rather use `...CARD = '''+name+''' ORDER...`

   - As far as I'm aware single quotes is the ANSI standard. Even if some databases permit double quotes, using them limits portability, and may produce unexpected results when passed through certain data access drivers.
5. Check the datatype of your `CARD` column. If it's a fixed length string, then the data values will be padded. E.g. if `CARD` is `char(10)`, then you might actually need to look for `'Ash Imp   '`.

   - Similarly, the actual value may contain spaces before / after the words. Use select without WHERE and check the actual value of the column. You could also check whether `SELECT * FROM Spells WHERE CARD LIKE '%Ash Imp%'` works.

Finally, as others have suggested, you're better off using a parameterised query rather dynamically building the query up yourself.

- Your code will be more readable and flexible.
- You can make your code strongly typed; and so avoid converting things like numbers and dates into strings.
- You won't need to worry about the peculiarities of date formatting.
- You eliminate some security concerns.

Comment: ok i have tried using ' and stilll no good.. but if i use `sql.Add('SELECT * FROM Spells');` it does find the records. yes i have `Close` `sql.clear`  `sql.add` `Open`  any other suggestions?

Comment: @GlenMorse I've added an option I forgot to include first time around. Also, have you run the query directly on the database to confirm no other problems. Using `SELECT * FROM Spells` is a similar elimination technique, but not exactly the same. So running your intended query directly on the DB is still important.

Answer (score 2):

> @GordonLinoff all fields in db are all caps

If that is true then that is your problem.  SQL usually performs case sensitive comparisons of character/string values unless you tell it not to do so, such as with `STRCMP()` (MySQL 4+), `LOWER()` or `UPPER()` (SQLServer, Firebird), etc.  I would also go as far as wrapping the conditions in parenthesis as well:

```
sql.Text := 'SELECT * FROM Spells WHERE (NEED_2_TARGET = 1) AND (STRCMP(CARD, "'+name+'") = 0) ORDER by ID';
```

```
sql.Text := 'SELECT * FROM Spells WHERE (NEED_2_TARGET = 1) AND (LOWER(CARD) = "'+LowerCase(name)+'") ORDER by ID';
```

```
sql.Text := 'SELECT * FROM Spells WHERE (NEED_2_TARGET = 1) AND (UPPER(CARD) = "'+UpperCase(name)+'") ORDER by ID';
```

Comment: Except that's NOT true, based on the data he posted and the value stated to be in `name`. Neither `name` or the content of the column are all caps.

Comment: I did say "**IF** that is true" :)

Comment: I know. I didn't downvote. :-) Just pointing out that the poster has made several misrepresentations of the facts here already, including this one when the posted data clearly shows it's not.

Comment: @GlenMorse: "Ash Imp", the CARD column. (Gordon referenced "comparing values", which means "matching content", and you replied "all fields in db are all caps".

Comment: @KenWhite can you see the data i posted? even if i made a mistake, between field and field titles, you should not even have to have me tell you this info..

Comment: @Glen: It's not necessary to flood my inbox from both the question and the answer at the same time. Please stop.

Comment: @RemyLebeau  i had made mistake , but the comparesion is not the issue. only the field Titles are all caps. I will try the ( ) around the conditions

Comment: @RemyLebeau said: "_SQL usually performs case sensitive comparisons_". I seriously doubt the veracity of that statement. E.g. In MS SQL Server it depends on the _collation_ of the column; which by default will be the same as server collation; which in turn is case **insensitive** by default. So the statement is at least false for MS SQL Server, and at best is platform dependent.

Comment: cc: @CraigYoung - When Gordon Linoff said that ""Access is case sensitive when comparing values" he was incorrect. Look [here](http://pastebin.com/Wi5B0Bwh).

Comment: use query parameters for avoid sql injection