# Database error - cursor not returned from query

Tags: sql, sqlite, delphi, delphi-xe4

Had an issue with "cursor not returned from query" and found a solution that basicaly reopens the query once more:

```
procedure TForm2.AdvGlowButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
with ClientdataSet1 do
begin
Close;
CommandText :='';
CommandText :='INSERT INTO TLOG (LOKACIJA_ID,OPOMBA) VALUES (:a1,:a2)';
Params.ParamByName('a1').Value :=  Form3.ClientDataSet4.FieldByName('LOKACIJA_ID').AsString;
Params.ParamByName('a2').Value := cxMemo1.Text;
Execute;
CommandText :='';
CommandText :='SELECT * FROM TLOG WHERE LOKACIJA_ID =:a1';
Params.ParamByName('a1').Value := Form3.ClientDataSet4.FieldByName('LOKACIJA_ID').AsString;
Open;
end;
```

Now,I am wondering if this is the right approach or is there another way around this error? If I try and open the dataset after first execute (delete the rest)I get the mentioned error. Is this the way this is supposed to function? This is a datasnap client-server app with sqlite as backend DB.

edit:
The form with the dataset1 that runs this query uses another form (form3) i.e it's Form3.DSProviderConnection1 to connect to server.On the server side in ServerMethodsUnit1
I have a DatasetProvider8 which is linked to SQLQuery7 (in the SQL of the query I have: select * from TLOG). I suppose I could replace this query on the server with a table.Now,what I am doing is this on the FormShow :

```
procedure TForm2.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
with ClientdataSet1 do
begin
ClientdataSet1.Close;
ClientdataSet1.CommandText :='';
ClientdataSet1.CommandText :='SELECT * FROM TLOG WHERE LOKACIJA_ID =:a1';
ClientDataSet1.Params.ParamByName('a1').Value := Form3.ClientDataSet4.FieldByName('LOKACIJA_ID').AsString;
ClientDataSet1.Open;
end;
```

I am fetching records based on the location. So now the user sees only the records from his location in the grid.So if I am not mistaken if user adds or changes a record the data first must be inserted and then displayed again in the same manner it was fetched. Or no ? Or perhaps it would be better to replace that server query with a table and display the table itself with a filter (location_id) so I could just run insert query and just call Table refresh?

Comment: The reason you get the error is because you have turned your `ClientDataset.CommandText` into an `INSERT` statement, which does indeed return no cursor.  Why not try creating a method on your remote data module to add a record instead ?  You would then just `refresh` or `open` the cds on the client side.

Comment: I suggest you ditch the **with** statement altogether. It seems it's being ignored here in any case because all your references are explicit. **with** has a simple alternative, and simply isn't worth the potential is has to waste your time, as the following recent example will attest: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21371312/224704

Comment: No,just removed ClientDataset1....

Comment: @user3181689 Using **with** is still a bad idea. Follow the link I provided above to observe how a tiny error resulted in a huge and unnecessary waste of time. Considering the fact that **with** has a trivial and much safer alternative, there really is no point in using it.

Answer (score 1):

You have a number of options. The most appropriate will depend on the particulars of your environment and requirements. I'm not sure what you've got because you refer to `ClientDataSet`, which implies mulit-tier architecture. However, you don't seem to be using it in a multi-tier fashion.

#### Option 1

Based on [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21401165/database-error-cursor-not-returned-from-query/21401580?noredirect=1#comment32286447_21401580) I've updated option 1 to demonstrate using a query.

```
//Your dataset first needs to be linked to an appropriate underlying structure
//E.g. a Table, or a Query that selects from a single table.
//This example uses a query, and assumes FCurrentLocation is the "pertinent" one.
DataSet1.CommandText := 'SELECT * FROM TLOG WHERE LOKACIJA_ID = :a1';
DataSet1.ParamByName('a1').Value := FCurrentLocation;
DataSet1.Open;

//... Later / another method
DataSet1.Insert;
DataSet1.FieldByName('LOKACIJA_ID').AsString := FCurrentLocation;
DataSet1['OPOMBA'] := y; //Alternative to FieldByName
DataSet1.Post;
```

#### Opion 2

Implement `INSERT` and `SELECT` in a stored procedure, then:

```
StoredProc.ProcName := 'MyProc';
StoredProc.Params.ParamByName('a1').Value := x;
...
StoredProc.Open;
```

#### Option 3

Depending on your connection provider, you may even be able to simply put both queries in a single statement.

```
DataSet.CommandText := 'INSERT INTO TLOG (LOKACIJA_ID, OPOMBA) VALUES (:a1, :a2); ' +;
                       'SELECT * FROM TLOG WHERE LOKACIJA_ID = :a1';
```

#### Option 4

Some RDBMS's provide syntax for returning inserted/updated rows as part of the same SQL statemement. Unfortunately I'm unsure about SQL Lite.

Comment: @User3181689 It depends on your app but I suggest Craig's first approach. Just do whatever you want in the ClientDataSet (edit, delete, insert), then when you want to write back changes to the database, do ApplyUpdates(). TClientDataSet is very powerful, you should read up on it.

Comment: To open the table I use a query so only selected records are picked up from the table.This is important because LOKACIJA_ID is pertinent to a location so the records displayed are ONLY from a particular location.So when a user adds a record he is adding it for a particular location and it is immediately visible.I am wondering if this is a sound idea to first insert and then open in the same query?

Comment: @user3181689 I've updated option 1 to demonstrate using a query.

Comment: based on your first example was basically my first problem. I run the select query to fetch required data. Once I had it open,I posted but query wouldnt refresh the data so I had to open it again.Problem is that I always work with the data provided by the sqlquery. Or am I missing something?